# Can a souvenir be a non-physical thing?

Tags: meaning

From what I see in major dictionaries, the word "souvenir" is used only for physical objects. For example, a small Eiffel tower bought on a trip to Paris.

Can "souvenir" be used in the sense of "memory"? Like in [this song](https://genius.com/Demis-roussos-from-souvenirs-to-souvenirs-lyrics). "Souvenirs" in it were clearly supposed to mean "memories". However, the author was Greek and it's a song, which often have loose grammar, so I'm not sure.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Most instances of the sequence [**song as a souvenir**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22song+as+a+souvenir%22) in Google Books will match your context. So yeah - it's to use "souvenir" for "abstract, non-physical" things, provided they can act as "memory triggers".

Comment: Using "souvenir" to mean a happy or precious memory seems appropriate to me.  Another song that uses "souvenir" to mean a precious memory:  https://genius.com/John-prine-souvenirs-lyrics

Comment: Songs lyrics are a form of poetry, a medium in which the emotions evoked by a word are more important that the word's literal meaning. In this context, yes, the word is used appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not in all dictionaries, but [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/souvenir) [American usages] carries the metaphorically broadened sense

> **souvenir** [sampling especially American usages] [noun]
>
> 1. a usually small and relatively inexpensive article given, kept, or purchased as a reminder of a place visited, an occasion, etc.; memento
>
> **2. a memory**

[adjusted; bolding mine]

I don't know why this sense is not in their section *sampling especially British usages* as it wouldn't be thought too strange in the UK in appropriate contexts. 'Souvenir' and 'memory' are far from being exact synonyms, though.

The metaphorical usage can be – I'd say usually is – ironic, the souvenirs being unwanted but not easy to get rid of. An example I've found is

> – *I take away mental scars as souvenirs*

from a thread on [forums.contractoruk...](https://forums.contractoruk.com/general/142450-drinking-bourbon.html) which also includes a similar example considered to require scare-quotes round the unusual metaphorical usage.

Answer (score 3):

The OED, which lists a word’s senses in their historical order of
appearance in the documented record by year of earliest citation,
gives two main senses for *souvenir*, both attested in the late 18ᵗʰ
century by writers from England, emboldening mine:

> 1. a. A thing or fact remembered; an act or instance of remembering; a memory. **Chiefly *literary*.**
> 2. a. Something that is given or kept as a reminder of a place, person, event, etc.; a memento, a keepsake; spec. a (typically small and inexpensive) item designed for sale to tourists and having some association with the place visited. **(Now the usual sense.)**

Notice how they’ve marked the memorative sense as chiefly literary, while
signalling that the keepsake sense is now the usual one.

Citations for the first sense include “Versailles, where every stone evokes
a souvenir of the past.” from the 20ᵗʰ century and “Eifermann was
recalling, as her most vivid souvenir of the Hamburg Congress, the lord
mayor’s applause-winning declaration.” from the 21ˢᵗ.

There are extended senses as well, such as the World War I military slang where it
meant a bullet, as well as compounds such as *souvenir mug* and *souvenir
seller*.

Comment: ... 'This one's got your name on it.'

Comment: _Souvenir_ is a French loan word - _Survivance, dans la mémoire, d'une sensation, d'une impression, d'une idée, d'​un événement passés_ ou _Objet qui rappelle la mémoire de quelqu'un ou d'un événement_ (Larousse) The second is very much a subsidiary meaning.

Comment: A bullet is very physical.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other excellent answers, souvenir can be used ironically for something unwanted that is brought back from a trip, either a physical object or something non-physical. For example, a sunburn, a tropical disease, a cast on your broken leg, nightmares from witnessing a shark attack. Anything that you didn't really want on your trip.

Comment: Surely sunburn, diseases, and a broken leg are very physical?

Comment: @CassLopez Surely they are, and nightmares are not. Either / or. The point of this answer is not to simply confirm "yes, non-physical is OK" but to add the element of irony to the possible uses of souvenir.